# finding the principal arguement

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $(1+i)^{13}$ and I need to find the principal argument.
I did this:
$(1+i)^{13}$ = $(2)^{13/2}(cos(\frac{13pi}{4}) + isin(\frac{13pi}{4}))$  using De Moivre's Theorem, but I dont know where to go from here to find the principal arguement

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  Most authors define a principal branch by excluding the negative real axis (from the complex plane), so that a principal "argument" would be an angle in $(-\pi/2,+\pi/2)$.  However your textbook author (if there is one) may have a different convention.

Comment: It was a past exam paper question at my uni

Comment: Note $(1+i)^2=2i, (1+i)^4=-4, (1+i)^8=16$

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+i)^{13}=(1+i)(((1+i)^2)^2)^3=(1+i)((2i)^2)^3=-64(1+i)=$$
$$=64\sqrt2\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\right)=64\sqrt2(\cos225^{\circ}+i\sin225^{\circ})=$$
$$=64\sqrt2(\cos(-135^{\circ})+i\sin(-135^{\circ})).$$

Answer (score 0):

As hardmath's comment indicated, it depends on the convention.
For example, one convention is that the principle angle must be in the range $(-\pi, \pi].$  This is the convention adopted by Palka in "Intro to Complex Function Theory."  Another plausible convention is that the principle angle must be in the range $[0, 2\pi).$

I am going to **arbitrarily** adopt the Palka convention (above) in this answer. Note, that the problem **can not** be answered without **first** identifying *which* convention is to be used to identify the *range* for principle angles.

Your work identifies **a** pertinent angle as $(13\pi)/4.$  You have to identify the unique angle in $(-\pi, \pi]$ that is equivalent to $(13\pi)/4 \pmod{2\pi}.$

Since $(13\pi/4) + (-4\pi) = (-3\pi/4)$, **the** pertinent angle 
 (based on Palka's convention) is $(-3\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 0):

You may be aware that multiplying complex numbers add up their arguments. [This](https://www.geogebra.org/m/hcvXvQND) is a interactive demonstration of how multiplying two Complex numbers look like.

Now, your complex number is $z=1+i$, which looks like this on the complex plane:

[image]

Multiplying it by itself would double its angle. In other words, if you raise it to a power $n$ , the complex number would be turned $n$ times.

Also, it is evident that $8$ turns would bring it back to where it is already. So, we have the following diagram that illustrates the argument of $z^n$

[image]

---

Though I admit that this isn't a better method always, but it provides us an intuition of how to *see* the multiplication of complex numbers. It can add to your understanding and interpretation/manipulation capacity too. Cheers!